# Help proving a function is continuously differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So i have a function $$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$  that's differentiable at x=0 and for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ let  this be true:
$$f(x+2y)=2f(x)f(y)$$

So how can i prove that this function is continuously differentiable? 
I thought i could use any of these theorems: Lagrange's and Rolle's, but i don't know which one and how, perhaps should i show at first it's differentable and then that derivative is continous?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to show that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists.

We calculate

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \frac{f(x+2h/2)-f(x + 0)}{h} = \frac{2f(x)f(h/2)-f(x)f(0)}{h}= f(x)\frac{f(h/2)-f(0)}{h}=f(x)\frac{f(\tilde{h})-f(0)}{2\tilde{h}} = \frac{f(x)}{2}\frac{f(\tilde{h})-f(0)}{\tilde{h}}$.

So that the limit $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ equals $\frac{f(x)}{2} f'(0)$.

As $f$ is continuous, this also implies that $f'$ is contiuous as we have
$f'(x) = \frac{f(x)}{2} \cdot f'(0).$

Comment: No problem. Also I just noticed, by taking $y$ to be $0$, we get that $f(x + n \cdot 0) = n \cdot f(x) f(0)$ for arbitraty $n$. Thus $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer Actually, that only means that $f(x)=2f(x)f(0)$ which means that $f(0)=\frac12$... In fact (see my answer), $f$ *must* be constant.

Comment: I ,think that in the line after "we calculate", when you put $f(x)$ in factor, you have forgotten  a factor $2$  (4-th term) and also you have $f(x+0)=2f(x)f(0)$

Comment: these are really interesting findings, i appreciate the efforts

Comment: Your calculation is wrong. You should get $f'(x) = f(x)f'(0)$. Moreover you have not shown $f$ to be continuous.

Comment: @5xum Yes you are right. The function hast to be either constant $0$ or $1/2$.  I assumed the function to be continuous, but as the difference quotient exists, this implies that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is only possible if $f(x)$ is constant for all values of $x$.

1. Take $y=0$ and let $x$ be arbitrary. Then $$f(x+2\cdot 0) = 2f(x)f(0)$$ which means $f(x)=2f(x)f(0)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$. Now, if $f(x)=0$ for every $x$, we are done. Otherwise, take some $x$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$, and divide the equation by $f(x)$ to get $1=2f(0)$ or $f(0)=\frac12$.
2. Take $x=0$ and let $y$ be arbitrary. Then $$f(0+2y)=2f(0)f(y)$$ which means that $f(2y)=2f(0)f(y)$ for every $y\in\mathbb R$. From 1., we know that $2f(0)=1$, so we have that for every $y\in\mathbb R$, you have $f(2y)=f(y)$.

Using the rule $f(y)=f(2y)$, we can show inductively that for every $x\in\mathbb R$ and every $n\in\mathbb N$, we have $$f(x)=f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)$$

---

This last equality, along with the fact that $f$ is **continuous** at $0$ (because if it is differentiable, it is also continuous), can be used to prove that $f(x)=f(0)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$:

1. Let $x\in\mathbb R$ be arbitrary, and let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, there exists some $\delta$ such that $|f(y)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ if $|y|<\delta$ (continuity at $0$).
2. Let $n$ be such that $\overline x = \frac{|x|}{2^n}<\delta$. We then know that $|f(\overline x) - f(0)| < \epsilon$.
3. Then, since $f(x)=f(\overline x)$, we have $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$.
4. In the beginning, the choice of $\epsilon$ was arbitrary. This means that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ for **every** value of $\epsilon$, something only possible if $f(x)=f(0)$

Since $x$ is arbitrary, $f(x)=f(0)$ is true for every $x$.